# Strang, Introd. to Linear Algebra: An explanation of why the nullspace and left nullspace of this "Chess" matrix aren't the same.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

For this question, since the matrices are 8x8 I will paste images of them instead of writing them out in Latex.

Consider the 8x8 "Checkerboard" and the "Chess" matrices $B$ and $C$, respectively.

[image: Checkerboard matrix]

[image: Chess matrix]

Each has rank 2. As far as I can tell the nullspace of $B$ is the same as the left nullspace of $B$ but this same is not true of matrix $C$. My question regards why this is so.

Note the reduced row echelon forms (rref) of each matrix

[image: Reduced Row Echelon Form for B]

[image: Reduced Row Echelon Form for C]

As expected, we have six free variables in each system and the dimension of the nullspace is $8-2=6$ in each matrix.

Now let's consider the left nullspaces.

Here are the transposes of $B$ and $C$

[image: Transpose of B]

[image: Transpose of C]

We have $B^T=B$ but $C^T\neq C$.

In the case of $B$, solving $B^Tx=0$ is the same as solving $Bx=0$: the system is exactly the same and the solutions are thus exactly the same. The nullspace and left nullspace of $B$ are the same vector space.

Solving $C^Tx=0$ is not, however, the same as solving $Cx=0$. We can see that the columns vectors of $C$ and $C^T$ are different vectors. In fact, this becomes even clearer when we consider the rref of these systems

Here are the rref of $C$ and $C^T$, respectively

[image]

[image]

Is the reasoning above correct?

It's not completely clear to me how to show that the solutions to the linear systems represented by the two latter matrices are different, even though it seems, by way of thought, to be the case.